# Android Studio maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } giving error

Tags: android, gradle

My gradle file is

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
}


allprojects{
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
       // maven { url = uri("https://www.jitpack.io" ) }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

it is giving errors

Exception is:

org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'chartDemo'.
at
at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:484)
at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:196)
at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:98)
at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:34)
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript$ScriptDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BasicScript.java:135)
at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:163)
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.invokeMethod(BasicScript.java:84)
at build_bfx3jpmwd1klug7cln092ca19.run(D:\workspace_24mar22\chartDemo\build.gradle:8)
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)

Answer (score 0):

Add maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } in settings.gradle file not there